# Pycharm interperter uses the wrong path

Tags: python, pycharm, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to follow [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers#quick-tour-of-the-fine-tuningusage-scripts) instructions.
I downloaded the Glue dataset, and I am trying to run this command

```
python ./examples/run_glue.py \
    --model_type bert \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased \
    --task_name MRPC \
    --do_train \
    --do_eval \
    --do_lower_case \
    --data_dir C:/Git/RemoteDGX/MRPC/glue_data/MRPC \
    --max_seq_length 128 \
    --per_gpu_eval_batch_size=8   \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size=8   \
    --learning_rate 2e-5 \
    --num_train_epochs 3.0 \
    --output_dir /tmp/MRPC/
```

I am running the command from pycharm, so I use this configuration.

When I press the run command:

```
C:\Git\PythonEnv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Git/RemoteDGX/transformers/examples/run_glue.py --model_type bert --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased --task_name MRPC --do_train --do_eval --do_lower_case --data_dir C:/Git/RemoteDGX/MRPC/glue_data/MRPC --max_seq_length 128 --per_gpu_eval_batch_size=8 --per_gpu_train_batch_size=8 --learning_rate 2e-5 --num_train_epochs 3.0 --output_dir /tmp/MRPC/
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MODEL_FOR_SEQUENCE_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING' from 'transformers' 
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py)
```

By the error, I see that the interperter is trying to find transformers in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\transformers__init__.py.

What am I doing wrong? I set the configuration accordingly

Comment: Unless you have two parallel python versions running and just a PATH variable set incorrectly, it should be the expected behavior that your script is importing from the installed package, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I don't quite understand, I am running the code from venv, and all the variables are set correctly.
It should installed from the package, yes.

Comment: Your package is installed with Python. Which in turn is located under the specified Visual Studio path. Python is then looking for installed python packages from this location, which has nothing to do with the paths you are specifying for the *example scripts* (not the *installed module*).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the versions of the transformers module, the interpreter was set correctly